# MYSQL Check if Coordinate Inside LatLong Bound

Tags: mysql, coordinate-systems

I have a table in my data base to store some areas as below,

- id
- name
- north_east_lat
- norh_east_long
- south_west_lat
- south_west_long

Note :  I store coordinates values as Double

I have coordinate point that i want to check if its inside any of my areas and i tried below query but its not working

```
SELECT * FROM test where (36.206006 BETWEEN south_lat and north_lat) and (43.995311 BETWEEN south_lng AND north_lng)
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-within ?

Comment: In what way is it not working?  This query will not return anything if the point is not inside one of the areas in your table.  BTW, MySQL Spatial data types are made for this kind of things.  Spatial data types would allow you to check if a point is within any arbitrary region, not just a rectangular one